# DataTable.Select as DataSource of DataList

Tags: c#, datalist

I'm trying to filter data in my datasource which printed in datalist. I do know how to use datalist and there is no problem with that. The problem is with the filtering.

I tried this:

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)Application["Products"];
DataSet newDS = new DataSet();
newDS.Tables.Add("products");

DataRow[] DR = ds.Tables[0].Select("CategoryID='" + this.CategoryID + "'");
for (int i = 0; i < DR.Length; i++)
    newDS.Tables[0].ImportRow(DR[i]);

PagedDataSource PDS = new PagedDataSource();
PDS.DataSource = newDS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
PDS.AllowPaging = true;
PDS.PageSize = 9;
PDS.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

this.DataList_Products.DataSource = PDS;
this.DataList_Products.DataBind();
```

after that I recieved this problem:

**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ProductID'.**

I do have a property which called ProductID, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like you have way more code than you need. Also, you should take advantage of LINQ for this:

```
this.DataList_Products.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("CategoryID") == this.CategoryID).AsDataView().ToTable();
this.DataList_Products.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The new dataset (and its datatable) doesn't have the structure of the original dataset.

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)Application["Products"];
DataSet newDS = new DataSet();
DataTable newTable = ds.Tables[0].Clone();//this copies the structure
newDS.Tables.Add(newTable);
```

Comment: @JohnSmith glad it worked for you. would be nice if you could accept the answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith what i mean is, if the answer works for you, you should select it as the correct answer. That's the way stackoverflow works.